# -js- React "component did mount" example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get started with react. Having examining the code examples I came across with a pretty strange thing. This is the link [[React tutorial]](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). This is the code from the lifecycles section;

```
componentDidMount() {
this.timerID = setInterval(
  () => this.tick(),
  1000
);
}
```

So, when setting the interval why an arrow function is used ? I tried otherwise(this.tick() itself) but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: [Arrow functions don't rebind `this`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval needs to be passed a function reference, so you could write

```
setInterval(  () => this.tick(),  1000  );
```

This doesn't run this.tick, it simply tells setInterval to run tick when it chooses to.  The arrow function binds 'this' to be your component.

However  `setInterval(  function () { this.tick(); },  1000  );`  does NOT bind this to be your component, so you would need to write `setInterval(this.tick.bind(this),  1000  );`

If you write 
    `setInterval(  this.tick(),  1000  );` then tick is run before it is passed to setInterval, and the return value of tick is what will be used by setInterval.

I hope that makes it clear. 
setInterval just wants a reference to the function  :)

Comment: No diffrence between -this.tick()- and -this.tick-. I think it's because what Dan Prince has said. This is taken as a global object, so it cannot access "this" things :d Thanks people !

Comment: oh yes, this.tick wont work if called inside setInterVal, because when setInterval calls this.tick  it uses the context inside setInterval. So THIS will not be your component, but it will be whatever context setInterval is in.